# Ways of comparing Text Content between HTML Elements

Tags: javascript

As the title says, I am looking for a way of comparing the Text content of an HTML Element with another HTML Elements's Text content and only if they are identical, alert a message. Any thoughts? Greatly appreciate it!
(Posted with code): For example, I can't equalize the remItem's content with headElms[u]'s content.

```
else if (obj.type == 'checkbox' && obj.checked == false) {
    var subPal = document.getElementById('submissionPanel');
    var remItem = obj.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].textContent;
    alert("You have disselected "+remItem);

    for (var j=0; j < checkSum.length; j++) {
        if (remItem == checkSum[j]) {
            alert("System found a match: "+checkSum[j]+" and deleted it!");
            checkSum.splice(j,1);
        } else {
            //alert("There were no matches in the search!");
        }
    }
    alert("Next are...");
    alert("This is the checkSum: "+checkSum);
    alert("Worked!!!");

    var headElms = subPal.getElementsByTagName('h3');
    alert("We found "+headElms.length+" elements!");

    for (var u=0; u < headElms.length; u++){
        alert("YES!!");
        if (remItem == headElms[u].textContent) {
            alert("System found a matching element "+headElms[u].textContent+" and deleted it!");
        }
        else {
            alert("NO!!");
            alert("This didn't work!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What did you try so far, also, put some mock up HTML we can give you examples built upon

Comment: All this code is dealing with other HTML Elements created within the .js file. The only external and pure HTML Element is the remItem which goes directly to the HTML file to get the content. The headElms[u] content though is generated through javascript. Still, I am trying to compare the two contents and if identical (==) then an alert should occur. It has to do with my check Element's content function.

Comment: Just added this point to my answer, but you also need to make sure the leading and trailing whitespace is identical. So if the original HTML has linebreaks or indentation, but the generated HTML doesn't, it won't be considered equal.

Comment: Yes, definitely. Besides, I am originally taking the pure HTML's file content and then generating it again in another created Element through JavaScript. Then through the Unchecking of a checkbox, that element with the content that was unchecked should be removed.

Answer (score 4):

```
var a = document.getElementById('a');
var b = document.getElementById('b');

var tc_a = a ? a.textContent || a.innerText : NaN;
var tc_b = b ? b.textContent || b.innerText : NaN;

if( tc_a === tc_b ) 
   alert( 'equal' );
```

Using `NaN` to ensure a `false` result if one or both elements don't exist.

---

If you don't like the verbosity of it, or you need to do this more than once, create a function that hides away most of the work.

```
function equalText(id1, id2) {
    var a = document.getElementById(id1);
    var b = document.getElementById(id2);
    return (a ? a.textContent || a.innerText : NaN) ===
           (b ? b.textContent || b.innerText : NaN);
}
```

Then invoke it...

```
if( equalText('a','b') ) 
   alert( 'equal' );
```

---

To address your updated question, there isn't enough info to be certain of the result, but here are some potential problems...

- `obj.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1]` ...may give different element in different browsers
- `"System found a matching element ... and deleted it!"` ...if you're deleting elements, you need to account for it in your `u` index because when you remove it from the DOM, it will be removed from the *NodeList* you're iterating. So you'd need to decrement `u` when removing an element, or just iterate in reverse.
- `.textContent` isn't supported in older versions of IE
- Whitespace will be taken into consideration in the comparison. So if there are different leading and trailing spaces, it won't be considered a match.

Comment: +1 - nice to see pure javascript answer...unfortunately, I use jQuery to get that data (it's a crutch).

Comment: Would you please recommend a solution in the edited code block?

Comment: @KonstantinosKaimakis: I just updated my answer. There could be at least two potential problems. Can't know for certain without more info. Take a look at my update, and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: @amnotiam - Yes, I updated my code once more. Don't get confused at this point with the alert messages; just using them for testing each block of code. Now, the thing is, I am trying to check HTML element's content to see if they are equal with each other so that the SPECIFIC element with the identical content can be deleted afterwards. (Haven't written any deletion code yet)

Comment: @KonstantinosKaimakis: Alright, but if everything is working except that the content is not considered equal, then I can't answer the question without seeing the content. Have you `alert`ed all the content to see if it visually looks identical? If it does, then try alerting the `.textContent.length` to see if the strings are the same length. Also, FYI it's probably better to use `console.log` instead of `alert()`. Also, you could create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) working demo.

Comment: Unfortunately, the textContent method returns ALL of the text nodes contained within the div, not just the text associated with that specific div. Therefore, if you have a div within a div, each of which has text, you get the concatenation of both text items.

Comment: @JESii: You can target individual text nodes when needed and get their `.nodeValue`.

Comment: @squint: True, but my comment was aimed at folks on the discussion who might not know that `.textContent` returns the text from **all** child nodes. Also, the construct that you are referencing -- `element.childNodes[0].nodeValue` -- is not exactly straight-forward, especially when testing things like ReactJS code where span elements are inserted to add `data-reactid` values.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a jQuery user....

```
var a = $('#element1').text(),
    b = $('#element2').text();
if (a === b) {
  alert('equal!');
}
```

The triple equals is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

To compare two specific elements the following should work:

```
<div id="e1">Element 1</div>
<div id="e2">Element 2</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var $e1 = $('#e1'),
        $e2 = $('#e2'),
        e1text = $e1.text(),
        e2text = $e2.text();

    if(e1text == e2text) {
        alert("The same!!!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I will highly recommend using jQuery for this kind of comparison. jQuery is a javascript library that allows you to draw values from between HTML elements.

```
var x = $('tag1').text();
var y = $('tag2').text();
```

continue js here

```
if(x===y){
//do something
}
```

for a quick intro to jQuery...

First, download the file from jQuery.com and save it into a js file in your js folder.
Then link to the file. I do it this way:

Of course, I assume that you're not doing inline js scripting...it is always recommended too.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not using jQuery at the moment. It's just that I am trying to compare the two using .textConent and '==' but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A simple *getText* function is:

```
var getText = (function() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');

  if (typeof div.textContent == 'string') {
    return function(el) {
      return el.textContent;
    }

  } else if (typeof div.innerText == 'string') {
    return function(el) {
      return el.innerText;
    }
  }
}());
```

To compare the content of two elements:

```
  if (getText(a) == getText(b)) {
    // the content is the same
  }
```